# Removing the table row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I have a program which dynamically generating the rows in the table. I have very little control over these rows. As you can see below only the first cell contain the unique id for the row. I have to remove the row from DOM based on that id.

```
<tr class="odd">
<td class="sorting_1">
    <a id="strategy_4555" class="linkable" href="/strategy/4555"> Something</a>
</td>
    <td>Public</td>
    <td>10,000.00</td>
    <td>10,000.00</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>10,000.00</td>
<td>
     <a onclick="deleteStrategy(4555)" class="btn no-radius color-red"><b>X</b></a>
</td>
</tr>
```

The only close answer I can think of is:

```
$("tr #strategy_"+id).remove();
```

but this will only delete the content from that cell, not the complete row. How can I do this use jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
$("#strategy_" + id).closest("tr").remove();
```